# version of multiple files: all document in one .tex file

Tags: input, automation, texinputs

I am using latexpand to Replace `\input{fileX}` by the content of fileX automatically using the following command in ubuntu:

```
perl latexpand mainfile.tex > newfile.tex
```

But I am obtaining a warning message saying that input files not found. Any help?